# Is the math done by Spider-Man in Spider-Man: No Way Home real or just made up?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home* when Spider-Man and Doctor Strange are fighting with each other. Doctor Strange takes them to mirror dimension. Spider-Man realizes that Mirror world is having some geometrical shapes and he uses his knowledge of maths to trap Doctor Strange in the mirror world. Is the mathematical (geometrical) problem solved by him real or is it just made up for the film?

Comment: Are you asking if geometry is real? If not, it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: @TylerH Geometry is [a hoax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry)! :)

Comment: @TylerH Technobabble is a well known SF trope. OP is asking if the "problem" spider-man solved is something that you can actuallyapply geometry to, or if it is gobbledygook.

Comment: @Spencer So, you think OP is asking us to explain how fractals relate to geometry, how one can use knowledge of geometry to calculate angles, not to mention how spiders weave webs, and how the web's geometrical patterns and tension helps trap someone who gets caught in it? That seems way too broad and somewhat not related to science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @TylerH Since I haven't seen the movie, I expect little. But in this case I suspect the answer is "No, it's gobbledygook".

Comment: Well, he uses his knowledge of math to *trap Dr. Strange in his web*, and then leaves the mirror dimensions with Strange's sling ring, thereby trapping him.

Comment: How is this not a real-world science question?

Comment: @TylerH: "you think OP is asking us to explain how fractals relate to geometry, how one can use knowledge of geometry to calculate angles, not to mention how spiders weave webs, and how the web's geometrical patterns and tension helps trap someone who gets caught in it?" — no. The OP is asking whether the geometry terms used in the movie refer to real geometry.

Comment: The question was asked at mathematics SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335801/spider-man-no-way-home-and-archimedean-spiral-possible-spoilers but it was closed for lack of details and clarity

Comment: @Adamant How to calculate the area of a circle is *definitely* a real-world math problem. It should not have been reopened.

Comment: Why the heck is this question upvoted and reopened?  It is **both** unclear **and** about real-world science.   It should be doubly closed.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez:   I don't know if you're just stating a fact, but just in case:  The fact the question doesn't have a home on other SEs doesn't justify that it necessarily belongs here.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I am just stating a fact, in case people are interested to see what the mathematicians made of it

Comment: @ThePopMachine The question is asking about math, not about science. And it seems to be asking about abstract math, rather than something that actually exists in the real world. Moreover, it isn't asking for any mathematical solutions, it only seems to be asking whether or not the scene refers to any question that has been previously asked by mathematicians.

Comment: @MishaR:   In the sense that "real-world science" is not allowed, clearly that includes math.   The "real-world" means math that applies in our universe, not in the universe of the story.  The ("real-world") idea that there are mathematical concepts that need to be true "in all universes" counterintuitively **doesn't** include fictional ones since they can violate the laws of basic logic however they like (and do!).

Comment: @ThePopMachine I see your point. However, I think it would hold only if the question were asking for a mathematical explanation. But the question isn't asking for an explanation, which would be the key factor in closing it. Rather, it's asking whether the scene refers to an existing question, regardless of what the answer is. It's a question about the writers' intent, not about mathematical solutions.

Comment: @MishaR: It's a fair point.   I think the question would be much clearer, and the point that it is probably not off-topic would be more convcinving if you remove the passive voice.   The title should be like "For the math done by Spider-Man in Spider-Man: No Way Home, did the writers draw on real-world ideas or invent them for the film?"

Comment: @MishaR:   That having been said, I still don't find the question very compelling because there's not really any math mentioned.   I don't have the script, but as I recall, it's more like "hey, this is just a geometry problem" not "hey, this is based on a D3 Symmetry Group embedded in a non-Euclidean 5-dimensional manifold".   It's not specific enough to see how the question applies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In an [interview](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiug5v_1pn7AhV67HMBHSn3A5AQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbeforesandafters.com%2F2022%2F01%2F14%2Fheres-how-math-art-inspired-the-mirror-verse-moments-in-spider-man-no-way-home%2F&usg=AOvVaw3s2FopBrjXd5qb2Qjj4xcL) with the visual effects folks on the movie exctract says:

> b&a: I’m curious about the kaleidoscope thing just in terms of the complexity of it really, because I can imagine you design it, you animate what needs to be animated, but because it was so mathematical, whether something like the FX animation and technical animation side relied on that maths, or was it more sort of ‘faked’?
>
> Adrien Saint Girons: Well, that’s a good question. One thing that was very important for the director was that it was mathematical, that it was clear that it was Spider-Man using his education to figure this out. So the brief was really worked backwards, that is, figure out the end moment when he gets caught and what the math behind that was. And then we could figure out what the kaleidoscoping look needed to be.

> I went online and looked up mathematical equations and mathematical formulas that generated interesting images. **It was math art fundamentally**, and quickly you find all these interesting images of these spirals that are formed by straight lines. There were some very interesting looks that come from math. We also looked at dream catchers, where you connect the line and you can create these pretty amazing patterns just by repeating the same action over and over again.
>
> In the visdev team, one of the artists came up with a really nice concept where if you have a spiral and you connect the pieces in a particular way, if you look at it from the side, it just looks like loads of lines connected. But when it comes perfectly front on-camera in a more orthographic view, you get this pattern that looks mathematical and pretty.

So basically what I get out of this is that they had actually done research for the scene, and it was just simple shapes and patterns, so yes the math Peter did was real world accurate(if thats what you are asking)

There's also a [Subreddit](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwim7sON2pn7AhWX7XMBHY-2AlwQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fmarvelstudios%2Fcomments%2Fs2tqq6%2Fdear_mathematicians_was_the_math_scene_in_no_way%2F&usg=AOvVaw1n0kcr0XnsPNH5So_6fqSO) dedicated to the same but its quite inactive.

.

Comment: Well, they Googled some maths and shoved it into the film. It doesn't mean that it makes sense per se.

Comment: The second half of the second paragraph in your quote seems to be repeated as the third paragraph

Comment: "It was math art fundamentally" should be put in bold, since it answers the question.